# Isomorphism- product of ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

If $A$ and $B$ are two rings,and $\alpha$ is an ideal of A and $\beta$ is an ideal of B, then $\alpha \times \beta $ is an ideal of $A \times B$.

I have to prove that $A \times B / \alpha \times \beta  $ is isomorphic to $A/\alpha \times B/\beta$.

I guess I have to use the first isomorphism theorem. In order to apply this,

I have define the following ring homomorphism:

$\phi: A \times B \to A/\alpha \times B/\beta $

$(a, b) \to (a+\alpha, b+\alpha)$

How do I prove that $Im \phi=A/\alpha\times B/\beta$??

Thank you

Comment: project at each coordinate

Comment: You mean $(a,b)\in A \times B \to a b$???

Comment: No, it's $\phi (a, b) = (a + \alpha, b + \beta)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is right, you just need to go through the motions of checking things!

Hint 1: Obviously, $Im\phi\subseteq A/\alpha\times B/\beta$. Here's an arbitrary element from $A/\alpha\times B/\beta$: $(x+\alpha,y+\beta)$. Can you tell me something in $A\times B$ that maps to it? If so, you've shown that $A/\alpha\times B/\beta\subseteq Im(\phi)$.

Hint 2: Take an arbitrary $(a,b)\in A\times B$ in the kernel of $\phi$. The zero element of $A/\alpha\times B/\beta$ is the pair of cosets $(0+\alpha,0+\beta)$. Then $\phi(a,b)=(a+\alpha,b+\beta)=(0+\alpha,0+\beta)$. These pairs are equal only if their coorinates are equal, so you are presently at $a+\alpha=0+\alpha$ and $b+\beta=0+\beta$. You *hope* that $a\in \alpha$ and $b\in \beta$. Can you see if this is true or not here?

Comment: Can I prove the first step by definition? $Im \phi =${$\phi((a,b)): (a,b)\in A \times B$}={$(a+\alpha, b+\beta: (a \in A, b\in B$}=$A/ \alpha \times B/\beta$

Comment: By definition of what? $\phi$ I guess? Yeah, the key is to recognize that $\phi$ can hit anything in $A/\alpha\times B/\beta$.